# The function returns invalid values

Tags: javascript

Implement the getarrayproduct function, which gets an array of numbers and returns an array of the same size, where numbers[I] is equal to the product of all elements of the array to the right and left of that element.

Notes:

The initial array contains at least 2 elements
The array contains only positive numbers
The numbers can be repeated
Examples:

```
getArrayProduct([1,5,2]) === [10,2,5]
```

The first element 10 is the product of all array's elements except the first element 1
The second element 2 is the product of all array's elements except the second element 5
The third element 5 is the product of all array's elements except the third element 2

and

```
 getArrayProduct([12,20]) === [20,12]
```

The first element in array 20 is the product of all array's elements except the first element
The second element 12 is the product of all array's elements except the second element

My code

```
function getArrayProduct(numbers) {

  let arr = []
  let a = 0;
  let l = numbers.length;

  if (numbers.length == 2) {
    arr = numbers.reverse()
    return arr
  }

  while(true) {
    if (a + 1 !== NaN) {
      if ((a + 1) == numbers.length) {
        arr[a] = numbers[a] * numbers[0]
      } else {
        arr[a] = numbers[a] * numbers[a+1]
      }
    }

    if (a > numbers.length - 2) {
      break;
    }

    a++;
    l--;
  }

  return arr
}
```

Function 'getArrayProduct' should return correct array for:

```
[4, 5, 2, 19, 8, 80]
```

Expected:

```
"[121600,97280,243200,25600,60800,6080]"
```

Received:

```
"[20,10,38,152,640,320]"
```

and
getArrayProduct([1,5,2]) === [10,2,5] - (expected) and my result  [5,10,2]

Comment: Keep in mind that `reverse()` does [in-place array modification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Comment: Also your approach in general looks strange. Why infinite loop in first place? Why not simply calculate a product (1 reduce) and then map array to `prod/item` (1 map). Do you expect your product to exceed maximum safe integer?

Comment: I mean `function getArrayProduct(arr) {
  const prod = arr.reduce((a, b) => a*b)
  return arr.map(item => prod/item)
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternate approach:
Eg: [1,5,2]
Multiply all the numbers in array at once. you will get ans 1x5x2 = 10

now your output array will be [product/1, product/5, product/2] == [10/1,10/5,10/2] == [10,2,5]

This method will remove the effort of multiplying same numbers again and again, for each index in array.

```
function getArrayProduct(numbers) {

  let arr = []
  let product = 1, i=0;

for (i=0;i<numbers.length;i++){
    product=product*numbers[i];
}

for(i=0;i<numbers.length;i++)
{ 
    arr[i] = product/numbers[i];
}

return arr;
}
```